# Running 3 Insert methods as transaction

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a repository where I have common methods for adding etc.

And I would like to run 3 methods as a transaction. Is that possible if each of them have "SaveChanges()" in them?

e.g

```
_somerep.AddCamel("test");

_somerep.AddGoo("test");

_somerep.AddGopher("test");
```

/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the repository uses a single entity context and all insertions are handled by a single call to `context.SaveChanges()`, they are automatically enrolled in a transaction by Entity Framework.

You can also manage transactions via [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) as mentioned here (but I wouldn't suggest it since it requires Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator to be installed...and can cause some weird issues):

[How to: Manage Transactions in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx)